# How to keep tracks of user(s) download(s) in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, model, controller

I want to keep track of users download on my web application so I decide to create a tables called downloads. I already assign the relation in  my model.

`Download.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Download extends Eloquent {


    protected $table = 'downloads';


    // Relations
    public function user(){return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id');}
    public function catalog_downloads(){return $this->hasMany('CatalogDownload'); }
    public function marketing_materials(){return $this->hasMany('Download'); }


}
```

Here is my `download` function in one of my `controller`

```
public function file_download($id)
    {

        $catalog_download = CatalogDownload::findOrFail($id);
        $distributor      = Auth::user()->distributor()->first();
        $export_type      = $distributor->export_type()->first();
        $product_export =  $catalog_download->product_exports()->first();

        $destinationPath  = base_path().'/app/files/product_export/'. $catalog_download->id.'/'. $export_type->id.'/';
        $file_name        = $product_export->file_path;
        $pathToFile       = $destinationPath .$file_name;

        if(Response::download()){

            $download = new Download;
            $download->title  = $catalog_download->title;
            $download->count  = $download->count + 1;
            $download->user_id = Auth::user()->id ;
            $download->save(); 

        }

        return Response::download($pathToFile);





    }
```

I have `downloads` table already.

For some reasons, no data has been save to the database. :(

Can someone help me take a look into this ?

I just added this block of code.

```
if(Response::download()){

                $download = new Download;
                $download->title  = $catalog_download->title;
                $download->count  = $download->count + 1;
                $download->user_id = Auth::user()->id ;
                $download->save(); 

            }
```

The rest is all correct.

Answer (score 2):

you have a `return` statement before your code, it is unreachable, you cannot do anything after a return...

Comment: I'm so stupid. Thanks. Also, I don't want to do my download logic before the download has been process. What should I do at this point ? I was hoping for a suggestion. Thanks @Junius

Comment: I change it to the top of my return statement, and it still not working. :(

Comment: I don't think you should use that `if(Response::download())` statement (i 've never used laravel but it's strange IMO)

Comment: and about the download logic before the download has started, in server's point of view, download has already started...

Comment: I was about to ask you about that next, you're right about that. How do you know that in server POV , download has already started. I tried to debug my code using dd(); It's not even work. Now, even if I comment out my `return Response::download($pathToFile);`, the download is still work. I am so confuse now.

Comment: Are you here directly serving the file or a page with a link that points to it ?

Comment: Ok, i didn't understand this, so you should serve the file via php and then use your download logic when serving it. [this article may help you](http://teddy.fr/2007/11/28/how-serve-big-files-through-php/). I don't really understand your last comment (the one where you are confused :) )